# Removing specific empty tags from XML through XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an XML of the following process

```
<p>In technical jargon<sup></sup>, the expect<span class="insert"></span><span class="insert"></span><span class="insert">ed</span> excess return on a factor is proportional to the negative of the factor covariance with the pricing kernel, <br/>given by marginal utility of consumption for a representative agent.</p>
```

I used the following xsl to remove span empty tag.

```
<xsl:template match=
    "*[not(span) 
     and normalize-space()=''
      ]"/>
```

Output through XSL. It remove all empty tags.

```
<p>In technical jargon, the expect<span class="insert">ed</span> excess return on a factor is proportional to the negative of the factor covariance with the pricing kernel, given by marginal utility of consumption for a representative agent.</p>
```

But Remove span empty tag only. So I need following XML

```
<p>In technical jargon<sup></sup>, the expect<span class="insert">ed</span> excess return on a factor is proportional to the negative of the factor covariance with the pricing kernel, <br/>given by marginal utility of consumption for a representative agent.</p>
```

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<xsl:template match=
        "*[self::span 
        and normalize-space()=''
        ]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to delete spans then make the template only match spans

```
<xsl:template match="span[not(span) 
     and normalize-space()='']"/>
```